# Ayuda con ejercicio de Java

Tags: java

```
int[] array= {2,18, 6, -4, 5, 1};
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  array[i]= array[i]+(array[i] / array[0]);

  //solution {3,24,8,-5,6,1}
 Yo lo pensaba mas bien como  por ejemplo
array 18= 18+ (18/2)
     6=6+(6/2)
```

pero evidentemente no es asi, alguien tiene idea?

Gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, lee [ask] explica de qué va el ejercicio y donde tienes dificultades

Comment: Ahí lo vi mejor, ¿Lo que  necesitas es armar lo que va a dentro del for para que recorriendo los valores de ese array te de esos resultados? Porque así como lo tenes da 3, 27, 9, -6, 7.5, 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, necesitas averiguar el proceso para obtener ese array resultante.
Lo que necesitas es divir el numero en el que estas entre tres y luego sumarlo. Al tratarse de int veras que no obtienes decimales.

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   array[i]= array[i]+(array[i] / 3);
}
```